# get session id after the session has timedout

Tags: php, session, session-timeout

I run a site in which people can login via different portals which are not always on my on domain.

When someone logs out they are redirected to their orginal portal url.

I have php session timeout set to half an hour, however I am facing a problem with which some of my users are sitting dormant on the site for over the timeout period.. as such when they get back to what they were doing on my site and reload the page they are inevitably taking to my home page.

I am getting a few complaints about this.

As a possible work around, I was thinking about:

> 1 - storing the session id in the db against the user.
>
> 2 - when the user passes the timeout run a check, grab the session id
>   passed to find who the user is then redirect to there original portal
>   page.

Is this good logic? I don't think i know enough about session id's.. after the timeout is the session killed at the browser, or can i still pick it up at the server end?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

Storing session_id is useless I think, as it wont be valid after timeout. Once the session expires, that's that. Once you call `session_start()`, garbage collection occurs.

Some options:

- warn user if there is no activity in 30 minutes then the current session will be wiped for 'security' purposes, then forget about the complaints as it becomes the responsibly of the user.
- cron job it, if you don't mind your server doing a little extra work, this could easily blow it depending on `$_SESSION` data size, the number of sessions and how often you run it.
- JS with a `setInterval()` to refresh (or a redirect if needed).
- meta refresh (with a redirect if needed).
- to set a different session timeout value for each user|section of the site. Here's a [post](http://markroland.com/blog/set-session-lifetimes/) that explains how to, I have never tried it though.

Comment: Hi gwillie, yes i do already warn the user. I do not want to extend the session in any way (via js, individual users). You say that once the session has expired that is that, however does the browser still send the session id and if so is there absolutely no way of grabbing it? I don't want to renew their session just simply redirect to a different url..?

Answer (score 0):

Each time session_start is called the session files timestamp (if it exists) gets updated, which is used to calculated if session.gc_maxlifetime has been exceeded.

More importantly you can't depend on a session to expire after session.gc_maxlifetime time has been exceeded.

PHP runs garbage collection on expired sessions after the current session is loaded and by using session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor it calculates the probability that garbage collection will run. By default its a 1% probability.

If you have a low number of visitors there is a probability that an inactive user could access a session that should have expired and been deleted. If this is important to you will need to store a timestamp in the session and calculate how log a user has been inactive.

This example replaces session_start and enforces a timeout:

```
function my_session_start($timeout = 1440) {
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $timeout);//change the session timeout
    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['timeout_idle']) && $_SESSION['timeout_idle'] < time()) {
        session_destroy();
        session_start();
        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION = array();
    }

    $_SESSION['timeout_idle'] = time() + $timeout;
}
```